# Create new cookie to edit its value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that you can't edit incoming cookies.  I have a cookie that I just need to read..nothing more but I have a need to remove some characters from its value so that I can parse it.  How can I do this?  I don't need to send the modified new cookie back in the response, it's just for my server-side consumption and then that's it.

Updated:

figured it out:

```
    HttpCookie facebookAuthCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[facebookCookieName];
    string cleanValue = facebookAuthCookie.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

    HttpCookie cleanedFacebookAuthCookie = new HttpCookie("cleanedFacebookCookie", cleanValue);
```

gayness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it too simple to say read the values into a local variable and do whatever you want there?